Correctly install and configure the drivers for the Broadcom BCM4360 Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter 14e4:43a0 rev 03 for Ubuntu 24.04
I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 on an old macbook air. I followed the steps and tips found in a  popular answer -> Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers
However nothing seems to have my wifi work smoothly and correctly as it is supposed to.
Sometimes the wifi connection is stable but very very slow. Other times it is both slow and goes up and down continuously. Other times it doesn't work at all !
So I thought about posting a question which is more specific just in case someone solved the problem for the same scenario or knows how to fix it.
My linux kernel version is 6.8.0

Has wifi power management been disabled?

@Jeremy31 Yes I modified the file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and set wifi.powersave=2

That is not a complete kernel number, it is missing the last 2 digits. Yes they are important.

Have you tried installing broadcom-sta-dkms and removing bcmwl-kernel-source?  There may be a few differences betweeen them
